# SAS Writing text to a text file results in extra spaces not written to the LOG file

Tags: sas

I have a dataset of address standardizations -- take STREET and replace it with ST -- and wish to write code that does the substitution.  When testing out the code, it appears as intended in the LOG file but extra spaces are added when I write to the text file.  I don't want the extra spaces.

-=-=-=-=-=-  SAS CODE

```
   data std ;
    
        length pre $16 post $8 ;
        infile datalines delimiter=',' ;
        input pre $ post $ ;
        
    pre = strip(pre);
    post = strip(post);
    
    datalines;  
    AVENUES ,   AVE
    AVENUE  ,   AVE
    BOULEVARD   ,   BLVD
    CIRCLE  ,   CIR
    ;
    run;
    
    data _null_ ;
    
        file "&test.txt";
        set std ;
        
    p1  =   trim(pre) ;
    p2  =   trim(post);
        
    put '&var = strip( prxchange("s/(^|\s)' p1 +(-1) '\s/ ' p2 +(-1) ' /i",-1,&var) );' ;
    
    run;
```

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=- END OF CODE

The SAS code produces the following ...

```
&var = strip( prxchange("s/(^|\s)AVENUES\s/ AVE /i",-1,&var) );

 &var = strip( prxchange("s/(^|\s)AVENUE\s/ AVE /i",-1,&var) );

 &var = strip( prxchange("s/(^|\s)BOULEVARD\s/ BLVD /i",-1,&var) );
```

... in the LOG file when I remove the file statement, but writes ...

```
&var = strip( prxchange("s/(^|\s)AVENUES    \s/     AVE /i",-1,&var) );

&var = strip( prxchange("s/(^|\s)AVENUE \s/     AVE /i",-1,&var) );

&var = strip( prxchange("s/(^|\s)BOULEVARD  \s/     BLVD /i",-1,&var) );
```

... with extra spaces inside the REGEX function in the file test.txt.

This is SAS 9.4 which I'm using through a web-based SAS Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your problem is based on how SAS stores character variables.

A character variable is *always* equal to the characters stored in that variable, followed by as many space (`'20'x`) characters as needed to fill the length of the data storage.  This differs from (mostly newer) languages that have a string terminator character or similar; SAS has no such character, it just fills the space with spaces.  So if the variable is 8 bytes long, and contains `Avenue`, then it actually contains `Avenue`  .

You *cannot change that* in code, outside of a single line of code.  So, your lines:

```
p1  =   trim(pre) ;
p2  =   trim(post);
```

Are meaningless - they do nothing except waste CPU time (sadly, not optimized away from what I can tell).

You need to trim *in the line you use the value*, as there it can be trimmed away.  Now, you can't `put` a `trim(...)`, so you need to compose your line to be written elsewhere, or else use the [`$varying.` format](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/vdmmlcdc/8.1/leforinforref/n0gyd5fptpa0ufn100pj7ghozy6i.htm).

Here's one example:

```
filename tempfile temp;

data _null_ ;    
    file tempfile;
    set std ;        
    result = cats('&var = strip( prxchange("s/(^|\s)',pre,catx(' ','\s/',post,'/i",-1,&var) );'));
    put  result ;

run;

data _null_;
  infile tempfile;
  input @;
  put _infile_;
run;
```

Here's an example using `$varying.`:

```
data _null_ ;    
    file tempfile;
    set std ;        
    varlen_pre = length(pre);
    varlen_post = length(post);
      put '&var = strip( prxchange("s/(^|\s)' pre $varying16. varlen_pre  '\s/ ' post $varying8. varlen_post  ' /i",-1,&var) );' ;

run;
```

As to why your log doesn't match the file, that's because SAS has slightly different rules for when it writes to logs than when it writes to files.  It's much more exact about what it writes to a file; you say it, it writes it.  For logs it has a few places where it removes spaces for you, presumably to make logs more readable, as it's not as necessary to be precise.  This can be a pain when you DO want the precision in the log, and of course in your case where you want the log to match what you're seeing...

---

Finally, a note on what you're doing.  I don't highly recommend using a regex the way you're using it.  It's *very* slow.  Unless you're only doing a handful of replacements, or only have a small dataset size, or really don't care how long this takes...

If it's just 1:1 replacements, I'd recommend `tranwrd`, which is much faster.  See just this small comparison:

```
data in_data;
  do _n_ = 1 to 1e5;
    address = catx(' ',rand('Integer',1,9999),'Avenue');
    output;
    address = catx(' ',rand('Integer',1,9999),'Street');
    output;
    address = catx(' ',rand('Integer',1,9999),'Boulevard');
    output;
    address = catx(' ',rand('Integer',1,9999),'Circle');
    output;
    address = catx(' ',rand('Integer',1,9999),'Route');
    output;
    
  end;
run;

data want;
  set in_data;

  rx_ave  = prxparse('s/(^|\s)Avenue\s/ Ave /ios');
  rx_st   = prxparse('s/(^|\s)Street\s/ St/ios');
  rx_blvd = prxparse('s/(^|\s)Boulevard\s/ Blvd /ios');
  rx_cir  = prxparse('s/(^|\s)Circle\s/ Cir /ios');
  
  do i = 1 to 4;
    address = prxchange(i,-1,address);
  end;
run;

data want;
  set in_data; 
    address = tranwrd(Address,'Avenue','Ave');
    address = tranwrd(address,'Street','St');
    address = tranwrd(address,'Boulevard','Blvd');
    address = tranwrd(address,'Circle','Cir');
run;
```

Both work the same - given you're already using 'words' anyway - but the second works in basically the time it takes to write out the dataset (0.15s for me), while the first takes 20s of CPU time on my SAS server.  Loading the regex library is really slow.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I never heard of the $varying format.  I don't see a button that says "this was answered" or similar and I'm too new to upvote.  Regardless, thanks again.

Comment: The "answered" is a green checkmark - should be up near the upvoting.  I did add some more details if they're helpful!

Comment: FWIW ... I just did some testing in SAS 9.4 on a Linux box with TRANWRD and it produces different results. Despite the reference to "word" it doesn't seem to find "words" like the function FINDW.  It seems to do a direct string replacement.

address = "1 PLACENTIA DRIVE"
... and ...
clean = transwrd(address,'PLACE','PL')

results in ... clean = "1 PLNTIA DRIVE"

Comment: @GeofGee Yes, it is not "word" like `FINDW`.  You can add spaces though - `tranwrd(address,' Avenue', ' Ave')` or similar - or perhaps test multiple times still quite a lot faster than a regex.

Comment: You're absolutely correct regarding speed.  I tried a test file with ~450k records.  TRANSWRD with 40 or so replacement lines processed the file in 2.6 seconds.  PRXCHANGE was 2 minutes!

I'm going to include spaces for most cases but check if the string occurs on the left boundary ... which unfortunately does happen.

Comment: If anyone cares, at the beginning of the steps, I add a space on the left boundary, use TRANWRD with spaces to define words, then remove the space at the end.